# Copy file using Burn

Tags: wix, burn

I am using WiX Burn to make my installer, i am bundling one exe and one msi.
And the exe needs an properties file at the time of install.
Is there a way to copy the file using burn, i tried Payload but it is not working.
Can i know the location throguh any Bundle variable where my file is copied.

Thanks
Ravi S

Comment: To be clear, the exe gets executed during installation and it needs to know the location of the properties file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you are specifying the properties file as the payload for the exe and not for the bootstrapper. For example, in your bundle, your chain may look something like this:

```
<Chain>
 <MsiPackage SourceFile="MyInstaller.msi" Id="MyInstaller" Cache="yes"/>
 <ExePackage SourceFile="MyExe.exe" Id="MyExe" Cache="yes">
   <Payload SourceFile="OtherFile.properties" Id="Properties"/>
 </ExePackage>
</Chain>
```

Also, as a sanity check, which version of WiX are you using? If you are using an older build (such as RC0), you could try updating to the latest weekly build.

Update: 
In WiX 3.6 it does not appear that you can get the absolute path of a payload file. There are two bugs/feature request open right now regarding the issue that are deferred to WiX 3.7:

- [Add burn variable to cache path - ID: 3557446](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3557446&group_id=105970&atid=642714)
- [Change working folder to the cache folder - ID: 3538846](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3538846&group_id=105970&atid=642714)

One workaround would be to use burn to write your own bootstrapper application and then programmatically determine the working directory and set the appropriate parameters, but that would be a lot of work for this one issue.

Comment: Hi Iam using like this, as the Oracle-install.iss file is needed during installation iam passing in the command.            <ExePackage Name="Oracle" SourceFile="C:\tmp-release\xe-10.2.0.1-nt.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/s /f1OracleXE-install.iss" InstallCondition="SelectOracle = 1">
      <Payload Id="OracleXE-install.iss" SourceFile="C:\OracleXE-install.iss" /> 
 </ExePackage>                                                And i am on RC1.

Comment: And one issue is OracleXE-install.iss should have the absolute path in InstallCommand. But Burn is putting in temp and how can i know the path of temp as it is creating a folder with Some GUID.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think you can give an absolute path. See my update.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, May be it will come in 3.7.